# I created a custom keyboard, on pressing down key I want to move to the next EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

This is my  custom keyboard:

[image: keyboard]

On pressing down key i want to move the next text view. Same in the case of up key to move the the previous textview.
Here is my code of keyboard.xml:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


android:keyWidth="15%p" android:horizontalGap="2dp"
android:verticalGap="2dp" android:keyHeight="40dip"

>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"

        />
    <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" />
    <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3"  />
    <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4"  />
    <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />
    <Key android:codes="67" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
         />
    <Key android:codes="55005" android:keyLabel="up"

        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        />

</Row>


<Row>
    <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" />
    <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" />
    <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" />
    <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyLabel="hide"
                          />

    <Key android:codes="66" android:keyLabel="down"  android:keyEdgeFlags="right"


        />
</Row>

</Keyboard>
```

this is the onkey() method

```
 @Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);


}
```

code:66 is performing the enter functionality but not moving to the next textview 
  can anybody guide me how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is hte main idea, you have to customize it depened on your needs

add the following to your XML layout

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/txt1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      (( android:imeOptions="actionNext"))/>
```

and

```
txt1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
      if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
           (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
      {
            // Perform action on Enter key press
            txt1.clearFocus();
            txt2.requestFocus();
            return true;
      }
      return false;
}});
```

Comment: its working fine, i want to hide keyboard on keyboard button . can you guide me

Comment: use this code to hide keyboard   public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        if (activity != null && activity.getWindow() != null && activity.getWindow().getDecorView() != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

    }